# Do ink compiler automatically generate getter function for state variable ( if declared as public ) like solidity language?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, openbrush

In the case of solidity language -

In smart contracts, state variables can be made public to allow for easy access and visibility of the data stored in the contract. When a state variable is declared as public, a getter function is automatically generated by the compiler, which allows any external entity to access the current value of that variable.

so, is it also possible to ink smart contracts?

```
// SPDX-License-identifier:MIT
```

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract NFT is ERC721URIStorage{
uint public tokenCount;

......
......
......
......
......

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also [calculate the storage keys](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/782) and use the `getStorage` method to avoid implementing getters.

If you have a contract with storage as follows:

```rs
    // Contract storage
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Dapp {
        accounts: Lazy<Vec<AccountId>>,
    }
```

And storage in your JSON ABI as follows:

```json
            {
              "layout": {
                "root": {
                  "layout": {
                    "leaf": {
                      "key": "0x87c1e648",
                      "ty": "8"
                    }
                  },
                  "root_key": "0x87c1e648"
                }
              },
              "name": "accounts"
            },
```

Then you can get the relevant storage key from the ABI using the following functions, although there is probably a better way in polkadot-js to do this.

```ts
class YourClass extends ContractPromise {
    async getStorageKey(storageName: string): Promise<`0x${string}`> {

        // Get the storage entry from the JSON which is the abi in ContractPromise
        // Assuming here that you're in a class that extends ContractPromise
        const json = this.abi.json

        // Returns the JSON object above
        let storage = json.storage.root.layout.struct.fields.filter(
            (obj: { name: string }) => obj.name === storageName
        )[0]

        if (storage) {
            while ('root' in storage.layout) {
                storage = storage.layout.root
            }
            const rootKey = storage.root_key
            const rootKeyReversed = reverseHexString(rootKey.slice(2))
            return `0x${rootKeyReversed}`
        }
        throw new Error('Storage entry not found')
    }
}
```

```ts
// used to reverse the hex key 0x87c1e648 above, swapping the Endianness
function reverseHexString(str: string): string {
    return (
        str
            .match(/.{1,2}/g)
            ?.reverse()
            .join('') || ''
    )
}
```

Now get your storage with this code, again assuming you're in `YourClass` extending `ContractPromise`.

```ts
import { firstValueFrom } from 'rxjs'

const storageKey = getStorageKey('accounts')
const type = 'Vec<AccountId>'
const promiseResult = api.rx.call.contractsApi.getStorage(contractAddress, storageKey)
const result = await firstValueFrom(promiseResult)
if (result) {
    const optionBytes = this.abi.registry.createType('Option<Bytes>', result)
    const accounts = this.abi.registry.createType(type, [optionBytes.unwrap().toU8a(true)])
    console.log(accounts)
}
```

Obviously, this process gets more complicated as your storage types get more complicated e.g. `Vec<Struct>`. Then you should be able to use [typegen](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/tree/master/docs/api/examples/promise/typegen) to generate your contract types, import them to the API, and construct them from the results of `getStorage`.

Answer (score 2):

No, ink! does not generate the getter. You've to manually implement the getters.

```rust
#[ink::contract]
mod contracts {
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Contracts {
        value: bool,
    }

    impl Contracts {
        /// Getter for self.value
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get(&self) -> bool {
            self.value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For simple values you can use `getStorage` and avoid bloating contract size by creating unnecessary getters.